# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context explanation?

Tags: php, sql

I'm getting this strange error which I have never got before.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Chat.php (class)

```
<?php
class Chat {
private $_data = array(),
        $_db;

public function __construct($row){
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    $this->_data = $row;

}

public function send($fields = array()) {
    $this->_db->insert('messages', $fields); <------- ERROR
 }
```

When I call the send function like this:

```
Chat::send(array(
'message' => Input::get('message'),
'author' => $user->data()->username,
'ts' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
));
```

The error pops up.

Comment: You need to intantiate a Chat object (passing your database connection into the constructor) before you can call the send() method, because it isn't a static method

Comment: `$this` is the object that was used in a call like `$object->send()`. You didn't apply the method to an object, what do you expect `$this` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object with `new`, so that there will be a `$this` object:

```
$chat = new Chat($row);
$chat->Send(array(
    'message' => Input::get('message'),
    'author' => $user->data()->username,
    'ts' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
));
```

You don't create the database connection until the constructor is called, which happens when `new` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `send()` function `static`ally (although it is not defined as such) by using the operator `::`. Because you are using `$this` in your function, it expects an object to have been created by the `__construct()` method, but this does not happen in a `static function`. If you create a new instance of the `Chat` object using `$chat = new Chat($row)` then `$this` will refer to that object in the function, which should be called using the `->` operator as in `$chat->send()`.

```
// Create a new Chat object using __construct( $row ), creating $this
$chat = new Chat( $row );
// Call send() method on the $chat object
$chat->send( array() ); // add your data
```

See the documentation for the [static keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.